# UCS2 and unicode C and mysql

Tags: mysql, c, character-encoding

I'm writing an application where I receive a char from network, for example char "ص" and I have the same char saved in DB from a PHP page, I can see that the char in DB is saved like this 0xd8b5 but the one I receive from network is like 0x0635. How can I change either of them to the other for comparison purposes?

I'm trying to understand the difference between ucs2 and utf16, what is the relationship between these two?

Answer (score 1):

When you see the char "ص" in DB as 0xd8b5, it is in UTF8 encoding.  When you see 0x0635, it is in UTF16 encoding.  I believe the UCS2 encoding would also be 0x0635.  Thus you have a UTF8 versus UTF16 situation, not a UCS2 versus UTF16.

Comment: that's correct, how can change it between them? I mean utf8 to ucs2?